# How to maintain environment variables for C# application deployed in Kubernetes other than configmap

Tags: c#, kubernetes, environment-variables, config

How to maintain environment variables for C# application deployed in Kubernetes other than configmap?

Currently all environment variables for pod is passed from configmap. But due to increase in no.of microservices. It getting lot of env variables passed from variable group to configmap.
Is there any way maximum env variables get from c# code itself. How large organizations with k8s implementation maintain env variables and no issue in deployment of microservices.

Comment: For large scale and more secure secret management, you can evaluate a dedicated secret management store like Hashicorp vault (https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-sidecar). Hashicorp vault agent can inject secrets directly in pods from it's backend.

Comment: You can embed environment variables directly in a Deployment too.  Is there a specific technical problem you're running into?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.